# MongoDB Driver 2.0 C# is there a way to find out if the server is down? In the new driver how do we run the Ping command?

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-.net-driver, mongodb-csharp-2.0

How do you call the `Ping` command with the new C# driver 2.0?
In the old driver it was available via `Server.Ping()`? Also, Is there a way to find out if the server is running/responding without running the actual query?
Using `mongoClient.Cluster.Description.State` doesn't help because it still gave the disconnected state even after the mongo server started responding.

Comment: possible duplicate of [MongoServer.State equivalent in the 2.0 driver](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29459990/mongoserver-state-equivalent-in-the-2-0-driver)

Comment: why would you use ping instead of a controlled connection timeout? If you have an high ping, when you will connect to the server your "total time to connect to the db" will be doubled (ping time + real connection time)

Comment: mongoClient.Cluster.Description.State is not reliable - noticed even after the server was back we were getting the state as disconnected. I was hoping to use the Ping to check the quick connectivity test and throw exceptions and not proceed to the query to differeniate connectivity exceptions vs occasional query/command timeout because of delayed return the response due to number of records.

Answer (score 3):

You can check the cluster's status using its `Description` property:

```
var state = _client.Cluster.Description.State
```

If you want a specific server out of that cluster you can use the `Servers` property:

```
var state = _client.Cluster.Description.Servers.Single().State;
```

Comment: I tried that but even after the server came online the state was coming back as Disconnected.

Comment: @HeenaPatel AFAIK the this reflects the status of the last operation. To actually check the connection you need to make an active operation and see if it fails.

Comment: mongoClient.Cluster.Description.State is not reliable - noticed even after the server was back we were getting the state as disconnected. I was hoping to use the Ping to check the quick connectivity test and throw exceptions and not proceed to the query to differentiate connectivity exceptions vs occasional query/command timeout because of delayed return the response due to number of records.

Comment: There is no Cluster property under Client when specifying a connection string. (v2.0.1.27)

Comment: @AdamReed yes, there is.

Comment: @AdamReed does your `_client` data member happen to be declared as `IMongoClient` instead of `MongoClient`? (good theme though)

Comment: @AdamReed don't really know what to tell you. I see it on my machine and [in the repository on GitHub](https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-csharp-driver/blob/master/src/MongoDB.Driver/MongoClient.cs#L83) (where it is for almost a year):

Answer (score 2):

This worked for me on both c# driver 2 and 1

```
int count = 0;
var client = new MongoClient(connection);
        // This while loop is to allow us to detect if we are connected to the MongoDB server
        // if we are then we miss the execption but after 5 seconds and the connection has not
        // been made we throw the execption.
        while (client.Cluster.Description.State.ToString() == "Disconnected") {
            Thread.Sleep(100);
            if (count++ >= 50) {
                throw new Exception("Unable to connect to the database. Please make sure that "
                    + client.Settings.Server.Host + " is online");
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

As @i3arnon's answer I can tell it was reliable for me in this way:

```
var server = client.Cluster.Description.Servers.FirstOrDefault();
var serverState = ServerState.Disconnected;
if (server != null) serverState = server.State;
```

or in new versions of .Net

```
var serverState = client.Cluster.Description.Servers.FirstOrDefault()?.State 
    ?? ServerState.Disconnected;
```

But if you realy want to run a ping command you can do it like this:

```
var command = new CommandDocument("ping", 1);
try
{
    db.RunCommand<BsonDocument>(command);
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    // ping failed
}
```