# How to check database connection in MongoDB

Tags: c#, mongodb

I would like to check the connection to the database. Is there a way to ping for server connection status in MongoDB with the .NET driver?

I have my MongoClient as (example):

```
private static MongoClient client = new MongoClient("mongodb://localhost:27017");
```

And would like to check if it is running or not.

Comment: Looks like this https://stackoverflow.com/a/28843508/5233410

Comment: This has to do with an old driver. client.GetServer() is no longer a thing. Please remove the duplicate tag.

Comment: Have you reviewed all the suggestions. The accepted answer is not always the one you are looking for. Many comments state it is for older driver and suggest alternatives.

Comment: You're right. I wasn't thorough enough. Thanks!